# Svn Server Setup, how to connect remotely?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn, subversion-edge, svnserve

I'm trying to setup a server for a small team trying to use SVN Tortoise with Unreal Engine 4.

I tried Visual SVN but had issues with it saying "An error Occured during SSL communication", with no idea how to move forward and how to fix it after several attempts

I moved on to Collabnet (SubversionEdge), anytime we tried checking out it gave us the error "No such host is known". But then I tried checking out with command line and it worked, (or at least locally) but after 15 minutes suddenly stopped working and no one else was able to check out for some unknown reason. After a couple attempts with no idea how to proceed.

I moved on to svnserve windows service, the problem with svn serve is I just have no idea how to ping the server if its working and what to put in the tortoiseSVN URL for checking out.

Side note if someone can also just correct me on what ip i put in for private address when forwarding a port that would be awesome.

Side note 2: if someone can also tell me a specific example of what URL for checking out with visual svn would be and subversion edge and svnserve that would be awesome and greatly appreciated.

UPDATES BELOW

We went back to VisualSVN and can connect locally but not remotely, when trying to connect to the desktop name with https we keep getting no host is known. When we attempt with the IP Address we no response and it takes too long and connection fails.

Comment: So i have a few other people on the team helping and we went back to visualsvn and its telling us now "no such host is known."

Comment: So we were unable to ping the server and i figured out how to fix that with the Windows inbound rules and enabling the i think IMCP or w.e, Anyways we can ping the server now, and i disabled the windows firewall, but people still cant connect remotely. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Updated........

Comment: Heeeelp...........